# Crawlera middleware order to enable httpcache

Tags: scrapy

I want to not use the crawlera proxy service for pages that are already cached using the httpcache middleware (since I have a limit for the number of calls per month).

I'm using the crawlera middleware, and enabling it using:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_crawlera.CrawleraMiddleware': 610}
```

as recommended in the documentation (https://scrapy-crawlera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Though, after a crawl ends, I get:

```
    2017-04-23 00:14:24 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'crawlera/request': 11,
 'crawlera/request/method/GET': 11,
 'crawlera/response': 11,
 'crawlera/response/status/200': 10,
 'crawlera/response/status/301': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 3324,
 'downloader/request_count': 11,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 11,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1352925,
 'downloader/response_count': 11,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 10,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 6,
 'finish_reason': 'closespider_pagecount',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 22, 22, 14, 24, 839013),
 'httpcache/hit': 11,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 12,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 10,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 10,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 10,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 23,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 23,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 22, 22, 14, 24, 317893)}
2017-04-23 00:14:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (closespider_pagecount)
```

with

```
downloader/request_count': 11
crawlera/request/method/GET': 11
httpcache/hit': 11
```

So I'm not sure whether this calls went through the crawlera proxy service or not. I get the same results when I change the crawlera middleware order to be 901, 749, 751.

Does anyone know what's going under the hood? Are the pages returned directly from the http cache without calling the crawlera server or not?

Thanks!

Comment: There's `'httpcache/hit': 11,` in your stats at the end, so I believe you used the HTTP cache. In your logs, you should also see the `'cached'` flag when pages are downloaded

Comment: And what about the crawlera/request/method/GET': 11

Comment: It means`scrapy-crawlera` middleware processed 11 requests (it simply adds the Crawlera endpoint as proxy for the request). What did you see in the logs? Do you see the `'cached'` flag for the URLs?

Comment: I see 'cached' but how can I tell if it didn't perform the crawlera call anyway, ignored it and returned the cached version? It depends on the middlewares order. From what I understand 'crawlera/request/method/GET' means it DID interacted with the crawlera server.

Comment: Well that's not [what the code does](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-crawlera/blob/0989221e68c7bf7bec1e596edca4ae86c5c16be6/scrapy_crawlera/middleware.py#L123): the stats counter is increased when the `Request` instance is processed, and `"proxy"` key updated. Nothing more. Have you tried disconnecting from your network? There's no log of the actual bytes sent over the network in Scrapy (which could be a nice addition though)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the number as just a reference to other middlewares.

```
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware': 600,
'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 610,
'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620
```

Just make sure **httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware** has lower number than the proxy middlewares.

This works fine for me.